# Not able to add and update objects correctly in state

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks, state

**What i want**  =>
I wanted to show a particular component when i click(select) any of the cards.

**Problem**  =>
When i click on a card, the **cards** state does not get updated according to the card selected. For example , I clicked on Welcome card and in console i am getting a blank array in starting. And when i select the second card(let say Invite card), the **current card** state gets updated to Invite card but **cards** state is updated something like

```
[{
  card: <Welcome />
  cardtitle: Invite
}].
```

instead of

```
[{
  card: <Welcome />,
  cardtitle: Welcome
},
{
  card: <Invite />,
  cardtitle: Invite
}].
```

Run the code once to understand better.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import Developer from '../components/Developer';
import Invite from '../components/Invite';
import Parents from '../components/Parents';
import RSVP from '../components/RSVP';
import Schedule from '../components/Schedule';
import Venue from '../components/Venue';
import Welcome from '../components/Welcome';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

function Home() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [currCard , setcurrCard] = useState('Select a Card');

  const addCard = (card) => {

switch(card){
  case 'Welcome' : 
  console.log(';hey')
    setcurrCard(<Welcome />); break;
  case 'Invite' : 
    setcurrCard(<Invite />); break;
  case 'Schedule' : 
    setcurrCard(<Schedule />); break;
  case 'Parents' : 
    setcurrCard(<Parents />);
    break;
  case 'Venue' : 
    setcurrCard(<Venue />);break;
  case 'RSVP' : 
    setcurrCard(<RSVP />); break ;
  case 'Developer' : 
    setcurrCard(<Developer />); break;
    }

    console.log(currCard , card)

    const present = cards.filter(e => {
      if(e.cardtitle === card){
         return 1;
       } else{
          return 0;
       }
    })

    if(currCard !== 'Select a Card')
    {
      if(present.length === 0 && cards.length > 0){
         
          setCards([...cards , {
            cardtitle: card,
            card: currCard
          }])
      } else if(present.length === 1 && cards.length > 0) {

          console.log("here" , present)
          setCards([...cards])

          
      } else {
         
          console.log('hhhg')
          setCards([{cardtitle: card, card: currCard}]);
      }
    }

    console.log("c" , currCard  ,cards)

  }

console.log("cards",cards)


  return (
    <div className="bg-black">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <div className={styles.main}>
          <div className="options"> 
            <h2 onClick={() => addCard('Welcome')}>Welcome Card</h2>
            <h2 onClick={() => addCard('Invite')}>Invite Card</h2>
            <h2 onClick={() => addCard('Schedule')}>Schedule Card</h2>
            <h2 onClick={() => addCard('Parents')}>Parents Card</h2>
            <h2 onClick={() => addCard('Venue')}>Venue Card</h2>
            <h2 onClick={() => addCard('RSVP')}>RSVP Card</h2>
            <h2 onClick={() => addCard('Developer')}>Developers Card</h2>
          </div>

          // current card
          <div>
            {
              currCard  
            }
          </div>
        </div>


        //show all the cards which are selected
        <div>
        {
          cards.map((card) => {
            return card.card
          })
        }  
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your updates are happening but you are checking for them immediately after callin setState. State updates are **async**. Better to check inside something like a useEffect hook which will run after the render update.

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log("cards",cards)

},[cards]);
```

The second array element indicates that the callback in this hook should run if `cards` change. If you want you can also put `currCard` inside it.